# JS - Remove value from an array in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

The question sounds simple, but I can't figure out how..

Example:
I have -

```
users[ userid1[u1XsessionId1, u1XsessionId2, u1XsessionId3] userid2[u2XsessionId1, u2XsessionId2, u2XsessionId3] ]
```

Both users have 3 active sessions.

"userid1" will disconnect from his second session, so I want to remove "u1XsessionId2" and end up with

```
users[ userid1[u1XsessionId1, u1XsessionId3] userid2[u2XsessionId1, u2XsessionId2, u2XsessionId3] ]
```

Also when "userid1" disconnects from his session, I will only receive his session ID and not user ID, but I have an array of all user IDs, so I probably have to loop through all users and all their sessions to find "u1XsessionId2". All sessions and users have their unique ID.

Comment: This seems fairly simple. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @tudor.gergely I have tried looping through all the users and doing splice if the session id was in that userid. That didn't work for some reason, I would send the code but I'm on my tablet now and I don't have it here

Comment: If you don't get the userid when a user disconnects, the only way is to search through each user for the sessionid. This be a nested loop like you described. Attach your code, when you have a chance. The problem is mostly likely there.

Answer (score 0):

```
var users = [
    [u1XsessionId1, u1XsessionId2, u1XsessionId3],
    [u2XsessionId1, u2XsessionId2, u2XsessionId3]
];

users[0].splice(1, 1); // removes u1XsessionId2 from first user
```

If you have a session ID value, but don't know the index (e.g. it could be session ID 1, 2 or 3 but need to know which one to remove), then you could get it and remove it like so: -

```
var index = users[0].indexOf(u1XsessionId2);

if (index > -1) { // -1 means it wouldn't exist
    users[0].splice(index, 1); // 1 second arg means remove 1 item
}
```

You can [read more about .splice() here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem is that I don't know if user1 disconnected or user2 disconnected, so I can't use users[0].. The session id could also be in user[1]. I first have to search through all users if the session id is inside. Also I have to access all users sessions with for example users["123"] (123 is his ID) I have another array with all the user IDs stored, so I can use that

Comment: @McPlažéér It sounds like you should combine the array of user ID's with the session ID arrays, such that each item in the users array is an object, with a property that is the userID, and its value is an array of session id's